# Restore List Items deleted via REST?

Tags: rest, restore

I called DELETE on an Sharepoint URL like `sharepoint.client.com/sites/my_site/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('myList')/Items(12345)`. I did not append `/recycle()`. GET `_api/web/RecycleBin` is empty.

Is there any way to restore the deleted data?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way to restore the item deleted using DELETE as calling DELETE on object actually deletes the item permanently. you need to append RECYCLE() if you want to send item to recycle bin on deletion.